Piping Enter keypress events from button HTML element to inside label element
I'm trying to hack up button element as a trigger for checkbox or file input. I've followed Styling an input type="file" button
I've tried to variants (all testing in desktop Chrome). In the first variant (myinput) the button gets the focus but pressing Enter does nothing. In the second variant (myfileinput2) the button does not get the focus, but the Enter does trigger the file input. In both variants mouse-clicking the button triggers the needed function.
Could anyone suggest if/how it's possible to get the both functionalities (and still working with built-in button element)? (i.e. have the button focused with tab and still have the Enter keypress/mouse-click pipe the event to the label)
Thank you very much!
There is a long discussion in Styling an input type="file" button, but as a non-web-dev it's hard to follow if it was possible to achieve this at the end or not.
<html>
    <body>
           <style>
            #myinput:checked ~ #bar {color:red}

            .hidden {
              position: absolute;
              width: 1px;
              height: 1px;
              padding: 0;
              overflow: hidden;
              clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
              white-space: nowrap; /* 1 */
              clip-path: inset(50%);
              border: 0;
            }

            </style>

            <input id='myinput' type="checkbox" hidden/>
            <div id="bar">hello</div>
            <button>
              <label for='myinput'>label inside a button: works</label>
            </button>

            <hr/>

            <button tabindex="-1">
              <label for='myfileinput2'><input id='myfileinput2' type="file" class="hidden"/>label inside a button: file2</label>
            </button>

    </body>
</html>


In general labels go around buttons (not the other way round) or are siblings - See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Also button elements cannot contain links or other inputs.

Thank you for rising this! It was mentioned in the linked thread that "labels-inside-buttons" are non-complying to the spec, but it appears to work, at least in desktop Chrome. Even if this is not a good way, I'm interested in this example as a test bed for understanding how the focus/keypress are piped / can be controlled and if it's possible to both have the button focused (as in first variant) and have the Enter-keypress go through (as in the second variant)

@Paulie_D Unfortunately your pen is no more available :( Please feel free to write up an answer, I'll accept it.
